# How to select query for certain value in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with my SQL query. I wanted to display data that their `file` condition = `no` and `status` condition not equal to `pending-update`.

This is my current table

```
| name  | file   | status        |
----------------------------------
| willy | no     | pending       |
| ash   | no     |               |
| wiki  | no     | pending       |
| Windy | no     | pending-update|
| wilma | no     |               |
-----------------------------
```

I would like to create a query that will display only this output

```
| name  | file   | status   |
-----------------------------
| willy | no     | pending  |
| ash   | no     |          |
| wiki  | no     | pending  |
| wilma | no     |          |
-----------------------------
```

As the output data for `ash` and `wilma` the value of the column status is `is null` meaning blank attribute. That is what I want to achieve for this query. But I have problem of fetching the `is null` value. When I run my query the row that has `is null` status value did not get displayed in my desired output.

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT name,file, status FROM tbl_geq where file = 'no' AND (status NOT LIKE 'pending-update');
```

When I run this query I got this output

```
| name  | file   | status   |
-----------------------------
| willy | no     | pending  |
| wiki  | no     | pending  |
-----------------------------
```

How can I fix my query and achieve this output?

```
| name  | file   | status   |
-----------------------------
| willy | no     | pending  |
| ash   | no     |          |
| wiki  | no     | pending  |
| wilma | no     |          |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-null.html) to clarify how to work with nulls. In short: null are not comparable and passes no predicate except `is null`

Comment: @astentx spaceship operator `<=>` or `distinct from` compare nulls as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must handle the `NULL` values explicitly:

```sql
AND (status IS NULL OR status <> 'pending-update')
```

An alternate (but less readable imo) is:

```sql
AND NOT (status <=> 'pending-update')
```

Keep in mind that SQL uses three-valued logic... a condition could be true, false or unknown. All comparisons involving NULL result in "unknown" which is not the same as false.